# Fetch particular pattern from file and read file

Tags: c++

I  have text file which contain some pattern(First I thought to use awk command into text file
into C++).The below solution works fine for us one single file.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151055/truncate-file-in-linux

But We are getting multiple file which also contain different pattern.So we need to write awk
command for each file which will not be generic solution.

Than after I have found lexer (Flex) for pattern matching in c++ (linux enviroment) But I faced some issue and could write lexer file. So I thought do we have any open source library in linux platform for pattern match in text file and convert into xml file. ( work in progress  for google but do not have any concrete solution).

In brief,
1)Search Pattern into Text File(In current, we are using awk command in c++ (in case any general solution)
2)Read Tabular format file into C++.

I hope I am able to convey my message.

Comment: This question is far too vague to actually answer it.  Are you sure you need to use C++ for this?  What are the input and output formats like?

Comment: Question too vague. What about PCRE and regular expressions?

Comment: As pointed out, the question has many holes. Supply a sample input/output.